# Change state of global instance from flask-socketio on message

Tags: python, flask-socketio

I'm currently running flask-socketio inside to a thread. On a specific socketio event, I want to change the state of a global object in main thread i.e, perform a function which might change its instance variable's values

In my actual program, 'self.params' is a list of chromedrivers. When a signal is emited a driver is removed or added. Does that make a difference? Chromedriver is a un-picklable object.

Here's a flask socketio code which a simplified sample:

```
from gevent import get_hub
get_hub().NOT_ERROR += (KeyboardInterrupt,)

from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
import threading

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'mysecret'
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")

class SomeObj():
    def __init__(self, param):
        self.param = param
    def query(self):
        self.param += 1
        return

global_obj = SomeObj(0)

@socketio.on('msg')
def handle_msg():
    global_obj.query()

def start():
    def run():
        socketio.run(app, port=5005)

    SocketIOThread = threading.Thread(target=run)
    SocketIOThread.daemon = True
    SocketIOThread.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
    while True:
        a = input()
        if a == '`':
            break
        else:
            print(global_obj.param)
```

How can i achive this? I get only 0 every time.

Comment: This looks okay to me. Are you sure you are sending the event correctly from your client? Add a print statement in the handle_msg handler to confirm.

Comment: Yes the function gets invoked. I am quite sure of that. Because I removed the print statement only in my Minimal Reroducible Example.

Comment: The code example above works fine for me. You simplified your example too much.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just checked. I'll try to modify the question's code... Though i cant put the actual code becuase it is too big and complicated... I thought it would confuse people even more

Comment: In my actual program, 'self.params' is a list of chromedrivers. When a signal is emited a driver is removed or added. Does that make a difference? It is a un-picklable object.

Comment: As long as you don't include your object(s) in the events that you emit it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice. I was just able to fix this problem. Seems that first declaring the common variable as None and then programatically assigning it a new instance created if it is None in the event handling part causes this problem. I don't understand why. Thank You very much for your help.